# Proper Path reference for multiBinding converter parameter with combobox control

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles, multibinding

With all the styling information around controls, and what's nested, control template, and triggers all around, I'm trying to figure out the following.

Take a combobox control. it has a control template for the toggle button component which shows the normal display in standard display (not drop-down mode) which shows the display value and toggle button to activate the drop-down.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="baseComboBoxToggleButton" >
   <!-- overall border covering left side display value and the actual toggle button -->
   <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

   <!-- area in left side (column=0) that shows the DISPLAY value -->
   <Border x:Name="ShowDisplayValueArea" Grid.Column="0" />

   <!-- second column using a path to draw the glyph down arrow -->
   <Path Grid.Column="1" />

   <Triggers for the toggle button ... />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then, you have the main combobox control that uses the template of the toggle button above

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboBoxGridControlTemplate" >
   <Grid>
      <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" 
                    Template="{StaticResource baseComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                    ... />
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So, I'm trying to ULTIMATELY change the background color of the "ShowDisplayValueArea" based on the results of a MultiBinding converter.  If I place the multibinding converter in the toggleButton control template area such as..

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiParmConverter}">
   <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
</MultiBinding>
```

The first "value" in the values object array is correctly passing the instance of the toggle button control template.  The entire object reference, not just the name.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, 
                      Type targetType, 
                      object parameter, 
                      CultureInfo culture)
```

So, how I tell the Binding parameter to pass the actual Combobox that the toggle button came from (ie: the parent to the toggle button) so I get the actual entire combobox control passed as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Found it... completely by accident...

While in the debugger of my converter class, I was looking at the object reference in the debugger window.  Then, since it was an object, I clicked on the magnifying glass to the right side of the "Value" column.  Doing so, brought up the "WPF Visualizer" (never used/seen that before).  So, seeing it from that perspective, and saw that it's "TemplatedParent" was actually the object I wanted.  There were obviously other properties I could consider playing with at some other time, but the TemplatedParent was the one I wanted.

So, I changed the binding from

```
<Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
```

to

```
<Binding Path=".TemplatedParent" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
```

and correctly got the actual Combobox control passed as the argument to my converter.  Now, I can utilize any/all properties of the combobox directly in the converter without having to explicitly pass them all individually.